# How to call a function in other function from html document - JavaScript.

Tags: javascript, html

I have one function inside another and I would like to call inner function from html document.

```
    <head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<title></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="start" value="start" type="button" onclick="start()">
</body>
```

And JS.

```
function first()
{
    alert("First")

    function start()
    {
        alert("start");
    }
}
```

Why in this case button doesn't work?
Thank you

Comment: The reason why the start function does not work is provided in many answers below. I would like to know why you want to do it this way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to readup on [Javascript function/variable scoping](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions). 
Your `start` function is defined inside your `first` function, so it is seen as local to that function. In order for it to be available/callable from anywhere within your script, it has to belong to the global, or for browers, the window object.
There are a couple of ways you can achieve this.

1) Define the `start` variable as a property of the window object, outside of the first function. Then, inside the first function, assign a function reference to it.

```
var start = null; //defined variable outside of any function, and so has global scope

function first()
{
   alert("First")

   //assign a function to global variable `start`
   start = function()
   {
      alert("start");
   }
}

first(); //when you invoke first, it creates the inner function and assigns its reference to the global `start` variable, which can then be invoked
start();
```

2) Using closure, return a named function from the outer function:

```
function first()
{
   alert("First");

   var start = function()
   {
      alert("start");
   }

   return start;
}
```

3) A slight variation on the above, return an anonymous function from the outer function:

```
function first()
{
   alert("First");

   return function()
   {
      alert("start");
   }
}
```

In (2) and (3) above, when you call the function the first time, it will alert `First`, then it will return a function which you can execute immediately or assign to a variable for deferred execution. For example:

```
first()(); //alerts `First`, which returns a function reference, which reference is executed right away, to the alert `start`

//alerts `First`, then assigns returned function to the variable `start`
var start = first(); //`start` now holds a function reference which you can execute anytime, like so:

start(); //alerts `start`
```

Finally, as a quick reminder, it is strongly advised that you use [event-listeners](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to assign events to your elements, rather than using the `onclick` or `onwhatever` attribute directly within the element. This also falls in line with the [principle of separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns).

Following from that, the updated code should look something like below:

HTML

```
<input id="start" value="start" type="button"><!-- notice no `onclick` attribute attached to it -->
```

Attach the click event listener to button using Javascript:

```
var startBtn = document.getElementById("start");
if (typeof startBtn.addEventListener === "function")
{
    startBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){first()()}, false);
}
else if (typeof startBtn.attachEvent === "function")
{  
    startBtn.attachEvent("onclick", function(){first()()}); 
}
else 
{
    startBtn.onclick = function(){first()()}
}
```

Comment: +1 - nice, solid answer. I like the variation on returning function. Only  thing I could possibly add is the obligatory mention that anything global is (generally) *bad*, and there are better ways to bind `click` event on an element than `onclick` handler (`addEventListener`, jQuery `.on()` - all used from within JS). ;)

Answer (score 1):

That's cause your `start` function is **encapsulated** inside the `first` function scope.

One way is to **expose** your `start` to the global `window` object by assignment:

```
function first() {
    alert("First");
    window.start = function() { // encapsulated but available to the global window object
        alert("start");
    };
}

first(); // Still needed in order to execute it and expose `start`
```

A similar way exposing the `start` variable outside of the function scope:

```
var start = null; // (Says hello to window)

function first() {
    alert("First");
    start = function() {
        alert("start");
    };
}

// Here `start` is still null
first(); // Now `start` is a function
```

Comment: Would this be sort of an abstraction inversion antipattern?

Answer (score 1):

The `function` keyword makes the name local to the function that it was defined in. Functions called from HTML attributes have to be global.

Then you have to call `first()` before you can call `start()`.

```js
var start;

function first() {
  alert("First");
  start = function() {
    alert("Start");
  };
}

first();
```

```html
<input id="start" value="start" type="button" onclick="start()">
```

Comment: I've added a declaration outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you make start a global function to call it from anywhere, even from you first function:

```
var start = function(){
        alert("start");
    },
    first = function(){
        alert("first");
        start();
    };
```